# How to convert string to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

**timeline.js + MVC + Ajax + JSON**

hello,

I have problem while converting string to Json Object

I have to display timeline on my webpage, I have used Timeline.js for the same, I am able to run the timeline using static data that is as following

## Static Data

```
// Create a JSON data table
data = [
{
        'start': new Date(2010, 7, 23),
    'content': 'Conversation'
},
{
    'start': new Date(2010, 7, 23),
    'content': 'New Conversation'
},
{
    'start': new Date(2010, 7, 23),
    'content': 'Very New Conversation'
}
```

now when I do

```
alert(data);
```

it gives me

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

but now I have to display a data from the DB, so I am calling the following function on controller

## GetTimeLine method on controller

```
public JsonResult GetTimeline()
{
      JsonResult jr = new JsonResult();
      var objtimeline = objEntities.Timelines.Where(tl => tl.StudentID == Sessions.StudentID).ToList().AsQueryable();
      String newstr = "[";
      foreach(var tml in objtimeline)
      {
            DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(tml.CalculatedDate);
            newstr += "{'start': new  Date("+date1.Year+","+date1.Month+","+date1.Day+","+date1.Hour+","+date1.Minute+","+date1.Second+"),'content':'"+tml.Description+"'},";
      }
      newstr = newstr.TrimEnd(',');
      newstr += "];";
      jr.Data = newstr;
      jr.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
      return jr;
}
```

## function to call controller method

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Content("~/Student/GetTimeline")",
    success: function (result) {
        data = result;
    },
});
alert(data);
```

it gives me the following alert

```
[{'start': new Date(2012,2,11,0,0,0),'content':'Parents meeting'},{'start': new Date(2012,2,15,0,0,0),'content':'Exam Meeting'}];
```

so the problem is with conversion of string to Json Object,

How can I convert string returned from controller to Json Object on my view...

Comment: I think you need to take another look at JSON objects and the syntax for them. If it's wrapped in `[` and `]` in Javascript, it's an array, not an object (JSON or otherwise).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Having an array as the top-level object is valid JSON. (However, the quoted string is not, not with those single quotes and that `new Date(...)` in there.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It would appear **I'm** the one who needs to take another look at the syntax, then!

Comment: @IT ppl: there's no such thing as a [JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) (well, there's *the* [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) in some browsers, with the `parseJSON` and `stringify` methods, but that is decidedly not what you're asking about). There are JS objects, object literals, and JSON. The result of the AJAX request **is** a JSON string.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Yeah, well, http://json.org is a bit unclear about it. The [RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-2) is more explicit, saying specifically that the top level can be an *object* or an *array*. Interestingly, the [ECMAScript5 specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.12.1.2) goes further and says that it can be any JSON *value* (so that would include just a string or number on its own).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're working too hard.  Let the framework do it for you.

```
public JsonResult GetTimeline()
{
     var timeline = objEntities.TimeLines.Where( tl => tl.StudentID == Sessions.StudentID )
                                         .ToList() //required due to Convert call
                                         .Select( tl => new
                                          {
                                               start = Convert.ToDateTime(tl.CalculatedDate),
                                               content = tl.Description
                                          });
     return Json( timeline, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
}
```

Then either use `getJSON` (since you specifically allow gets) or specify `dataType: 'json'` in your request.

```
$.getJSON( '@Url.Action("gettimeline","student")', function(data) {
     alert(data);
});
```

Comment: gettimeline method gives the following error - {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Comment: @ITppl I noticed that might happened and updated, but you must not have seen my change.  There's no translation for the Convert call and so you need to load the objects in memory before converting.  If CalculatedDate is already a DateTime, though, you don't need to do this.  Please tell me that you ARE storing it as an actual DateTime in the DB, not as a string.  If so, just remove both the ToList() and the conversion.

Comment: it's working fine at controller side, but it returns this [0] = { start = {2/11/2012 12:00:00 AM}, content = "Exam meeting" } but I want  start = (2012,11,2,0,0,0) as it was used in timeline.js, how to do that

Comment: @ITppl I'm not familiar with timeline.js, but it should be giving you an actual date object on the client.  What you're seeing is the conversion of the date object to its string representation.  That should be equivalent to what you were doing with your static example.

Comment: @ITppl I should also note that `getJSON` is going to do the conversion from string to object for you.  I suppose you could artificially construct the "date" as date constructor string, but by the time it gets to the callback it will be converted to an object anyway.  If timeline *needs* it as a string in a certain format, then format it as that string (without the constructor) for timeline before sending to the client.

Answer (score 1):

What you have the server returning is not valid [JSON](http://json.org). Or give your server-side code, it may be valid JSON which just defines a string rather than an object graph. In JSON:

- All object keys must be in **double** quotes, not single quotes.
- All strings must be in **double** quotes, not single quotes.
- `new Date(...)` is not valid (JSON doesn't have any concept of dates).

I believe you want to build up an array (not a string) and assign that to `jr.Data`, and then let the [`JsonResult` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470569.aspx) handle the serialization for you (but I haven't done this in ASP.net MVC).

Once you have the server returning valid JSON, ensure that it's returning it with the correct `Content-Type` header (the value is `application/json`). When you do, jQuery will see that it's JSON and deserialize it into an object graph for you. If you can't or don't want to make your server return valid JSON, add `dataType: 'json'` to the `ajax` call to force it.

Comment: yup i want to return the array from the controller that can be used by the timeline.js, what is other way ?

Comment: @ITppl: As I said: *"I believe you want to build up an array (not a string) and assign that to `jr.Data`, and then let the `JsonResult` object handle the serialization for you"*